# Are these rectangles similar?

Tags: geometry

The question in my textbook is:

> The dimensions of one rectangle are $4$cm and $5$cm. The dimensions of another rectangle are $4$cm and $6$cm and $7.5$cm. Are these rectangles similar?

As per I know a rectangle only has $2$ dimensions: length and breadth but the question above says there are $3$ dimensions in a rectangle. So Is the question wrong or is there a solution for the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are totally right. What I suppose is that the similar recatngle to the first will be $6 \times 7.5$ since you just increase by $50$% each side.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense so it might be that the dimensions of the second rectangle would be 6 * 7.5cm and it could be a printing mistake in my textbook.

Comment: I totally agree with you. You cannot concieve the number of typo's and mistakes found in textbooks. Cheers.